# how to search and replace string using reg ex in python in following condition?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

hello python experts !

I have strings like,

```
1. <li class="sli">First Session </li>
2. <li class="sli">Used <a class="xref" href="GUID-EEEEEE123-9ADD-E992-A982-CJHKL15414C-RTYBFDG.html">to initiate python session </li>
```

To,

```
1. First Session 
2. Used to initiate python session
```

Could you please help me with reg ex?
I am trying to create reg ex which will select "<" , ">" and whatever come within this"<",">"

please help.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Please take a look at this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/257501][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/257501

Comment: The knee-jerk "never use regex for anything related to HTML" responses are frankly incorrect.  If he has a list of strings that he wants to strip out all tags from, `re` is the correct tool for the job.

Comment: I'm in the anti-regex camp, BeautifulSoup should do it simply with `.string`. You should clarify if the `1. ` and `2. ` are part of the strings though, as I simply presumed they weren't (BeautifulSoup would handle it either way).

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-bounded problem so using regex for this operation is actually fine.  You cannot reasonably parse *arbitrary* html with regex, but you can easily strip out all of the tags in those strings.

Given that all tags are closed, this should work:

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'<.*?>')

s = '2. <li class="sli">Used <a class="xref" href="GUID-EEEEEE123-9ADD-E992-A982-CJHKL15414C-RTYBFDG.html">to initiate python session </li>'

pat.sub('', s)
Out[15]: '2. Used to initiate python session '
```

The key is making the part in between the `<>` braces lazily match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) if you really need to do it via a regular expression.

In your case it will be:

```
result= re.sub(r'(<).*?(>)','',data)
```

where `data` is the string that contains what you want removed and `result` is the output string

However as Max Noel said it is normally better to use some HTML parser.